# Horizontal Scrolling Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm putting together a mock-up for a new HTML layout. It's almost there, but I'm getting an annoying horizontal scrolling issue occurring on my header bar.

Although the containing elements are 100% width, the header seems to be cut off to the horizontal scrolling area.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: purple;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: Red;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
header {
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: Orange;
}
```

I've put the mock-up into a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8k51k83r/

Notice that if you scroll horizontally, the header seems to end where the horizontal scrolling begins.

Any ideas what I've done wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand this *the header seems to end where the horizontal scrolling begins*. I can't see any issues either. Can you explain a bit more? Also what browser?

Comment: Your problem seems to be with the display. e.g. if you put display: table on the wrapper, it seems to work ok.

Comment: You don't need `min-width: 768px;` in `#content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this:  `#wrapper{width:auto; display:inline-block;}`

Comment: Knew it would be something simple. Thanks!